# Creating a software for research

Tags: c#, python, graph, visualization, topology

Hello I am a beginner programmer. I've been learning how to use Python, JavaScript from Codecademy and little bit of C# from school.
Since I have never programmed any real programs and feel like what I really need to do to learn how to code is actually to build simple programs.

So I thought it would be a good idea to build a simple graphing program. Like this:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cn3ogzLzxuM (skip to 4:05)

I've done some research and I could not find any relevant information so here I am posting a question.
So how would I tackle this problem? (I am most confident using Python and for C# I would be able to get some help from the teacher)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the video link you provided , i would suggest using a [Processing](http://processing.org/) Programming Language .

From the *Processing* site :

> Processing is a programming language, development environment, and online community. Since 2001, Processing has promoted software literacy within the visual arts and visual literacy within technology. Initially created to serve as a software sketchbook and to teach computer programming fundamentals within a visual context, Processing evolved into a development tool for professionals. Today, there are tens of thousands of students, artists, designers, researchers, and hobbyists who use Processing for learning, prototyping, and production.

Comment: You have introduced a whole new language... I'm overwhelmed by the scale now...
How should I take on this language...?

Comment: I suggest you read the [Tutorials](http://processing.org/tutorials/) or explore the [Examples](http://processing.org/examples/) . Anyway if you are familiar with Python or C# that should be easy . The language is designed for beginners .